# How do I add a file to Subversion that has the same name as a directory that was deleted?

Tags: svn

A long time ago I had the following directory structure in my SVN repository

```
trunk/
    data/
        levels/
            1.level
            2.level
            ...
        ...
    ...
```

But I deleted the 'levels' directory long ago. Now I want to add a single text file called 'levels' to the 'data' directory, so it will look like this:

```
trunk/
    data/
        levels
        ...
    ...
```

Now when I try to add the file 'levels', I get this message:

```
$ svn add data/levels
svn: Can't replace 'data/levels' with a node of a differing type; the deletion m
ust be committed and the parent updated before adding 'data/levels'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running `svn update`. That will update the current folder's revision number and all associated metadata. You should also make sure `svn status` doesn't display anything related to this.

Comment: Looks like that fixed it, although I'm still not sure why. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's usually good practice to run `svn update` *before* and *after* a commit so that your working copy is up-to-date.

Remember that whenever you make a commit in svn, it doesn't update your working copy. So, when you commit revision 10, your working copy is still revision 9 (or something lower).

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates:

1. first commit the deletion of the levels folder (svn ci)
2. run an update (svn up)
3. add the levels file (svn add data/levels)
4. commit the levels file (svn ci)

Comment: There was no levels folder, that's what confused me... I had already deleted it many revisions ago.

Comment: If the levels folder doesn't show up if you run 'svn list url/to/trunk', then an 'svn up' should get your working copy to the current state again and adding the file should work.